# I can't make plots on the colab with matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, google-colaboratory

I recently had an error in google colab to make the plots I need. It pame returns the following error.

`ImportError: cannot import name 'png' from 'matplotlib' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/init_.py)`

It seems that it is connected with the version of matplotlib, because I looked for this error on the internet and one of the solutions was:

`!pip install matplotlib == 3.1.1`

It works, but it doesn't make much sense when it comes to Colab

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Can you add your code so we can help you ?

Comment: Of course, follow the code below:

```import matplotlib.pyplot as plt```  -> here I import the matplotlib

then I call the library normally
```plt.hist (array)```

Answer (score 2):

thanks for the code：

```
!pip install matplotlib == 3.1.1
```

it work on my colan

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32467902)

Answer (score 0):

- Maybe it is

  !pip install matplotlib==3.1.1

**Because there is no blank around** `==` .